# MYSQL - How do I unpivot my data to get the following output below?

Tags: oracle

Never used MYSQL unpivot much and its a complex example so thanks in advance.
I am looking to get the following query to be Unpivoted by COD_DUE_DATE. So I want the CASE_ID's down the column and along the column I want 4 parts:- Less than a week, due in a week, due in 2 week, due in 3 weeks ect.
Then the values in the middle will be a count of CASE_ID

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.CASE_ID, b.BUCKET, a.CUSTOMER_OCCUPATION_DATE,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.CUSTOMER_OCCUPATION_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-10000 AND SYSDATE+7 THEN 'LESS THAN 1 WEEK'
        WHEN a.CUSTOMER_OCCUPATION_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE+8 AND SYSDATE+14 THEN 'DUE IN 1 WEEK'  
        WHEN a.CUSTOMER_OCCUPATION_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE+15 AND SYSDATE+21 THEN 'DUE IN 2 WEEKS'  
        WHEN a.CUSTOMER_OCCUPATION_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE+22 AND SYSDATE+28 THEN 'DUE IN 3 WEEKS'
        ELSE 'DUE IN 4+ WEEKS'
    END as COD_DUE_DATE
FROM FND_COMPLAINTS a, FTTP_NEWSITES_DWELL_DETAIL b,
unpivot 
( 
a.CUSTOMER_OCCUPATION_DATE
for  COD_DUE_DATE in (LESS THAN 1 WEEK)
)
WHERE a.NAD_KEY = b.NAD(+) AND a.CUSTOMER_OCCUPATION_DATE IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY a.CUSTOMER_OCCUPATION_DATE ASC
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have an `UNPIVOT`... this looks more like oracle to me...

Comment: *" this looks more like oracle to me."* it is @Nick notice the  `(+)` operator which is Oracle's LEFT or RIGHT join feature  operator on top off the old comma join SQL standard..  Topicstarter Oracle advices not to use `(+)` annymore by the way

Comment: @RaymondNijland I wasn't 100% sure it was oracle (definitely sure it wasn't MySQL though!) so I didn't want to edit the tags. Thanks for confirming and doing that.